# Erro: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, sql

```
include "config_db.php";

$sql = "INSERT INTO tb_produto (NOME_PROD,DESC_PROD,VALOR_PROD,VL_COMP_PROD,STATUS_PROD,COD_CAT,TAM_PROD,COR_PROD,COD_BARRA_PROD,ID_FORN,MAT_FUNC, QTD_PROD,FT_PRODUTO)VALUES('$nome',$desc,$val,$vld,'$status',$cat,'$tam','$cor',$cbr,$forn,$func,$qtd,'$ft')";
$sel = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die (mysqli_error($con)); 
$caminho_imagem = "prod/ft/".$ft;
if(move_uploaded_file($ftmp, $caminho_imagem)){
    echo"
    <html>
    <style>
    @font-face
    {
        font-family:horatiodbol;
        src: url('horatiodbol.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <font size='+3' face='horatiodbol' color='#FFFFFF'>Produto Cadastrado</font>
    <br>
    <a href='prod.php' color='#FFFFFF' style='font-family:horatiodbol; text-decoration:none;' >Voltar</a>";
}
```

Esse código apresenta o erro citado no titulo, como resolver?

Comment: Alguma das variáveis está vindo com aspas simples?

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_produto (NOME_PROD,DESC_PROD,VALOR_PROD,VL_COMP_PROD,STATUS_PROD,COD_CAT,TAM_PROD,COR_PROD,COD_BARRA_PROD,ID_FORN,MAT_FUNC, QTD_PROD,FT_PRODUTO)VALUES($nome,$desc,$val,$vld,$status,$cat,$tam,$cor,$cbr,$forn,$func,$qtd,$ft)";

Comment: sem as aspas simples.. teste ai..

Comment: Já havia tentado mas sem sucesso esse metodo, mas já resolvi o problema, Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algumas das variáveis na query estão vindo com aspas simples `'`, fazendo com que mais de um VALUE se torne apenas 1, e com isso o número de VALUES se torna menor em relação ao número de colunas da query. Por exemplo:

Se eu tenho esta query:

```
"insert into tabela (coluna1,coluna2)values($abc,$def)"
```

E os valores das variáveis são:

```
$abc = "'foo";
$def = "bla'"
```

A query ficaria assim:

```
"insert into tabela (coluna1,coluna2)values('foo,bla')"
```

Veja que o VALUES possui agora apenas 1 parâmetro, delimitado entre as aspas simples, resultando no erro citado na pergunta (*Column count doesn't match value count at row 1*):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Solução e Sugestão:**

Antes de inserir no banco, fazer um `replace` em todas as variáveis tirando as aspas simples. Uma sugestão seria substituir as aspas simples pelo código HTML que representa um apóstrofo:

```
$abc = str_replace("'","&rsquo;",$abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso do seu **INSERT** o ideal serial alterar esta linha

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tb_produto (NOME_PROD,DESC_PROD,VALOR_PROD,VL_COMP_PROD,STATUS_PROD,COD_CAT,TAM_PROD,COR_PROD,COD_BARRA_PROD,ID_FORN,MAT_FUNC, QTD_PROD,FT_PRODUTO)VALUES('$nome',$desc,$val,$vld,'$status',$cat,'$tam','$cor',$cbr,$forn,$func,$qtd,'$ft')";
```

Para esta abaixo linha abaixo, com todas variáveis dentro de aspas simples identificando que cada campo receberá somente um valor evitando conflitos e também que o número de values seja maior ou menor que o número de campos informados na query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tb_produto (NOME_PROD, DESC_PROD, VALOR_PROD, VL_COMP_PROD, STATUS_PROD, COD_CAT, TAM_PROD, COR_PROD, COD_BARRA_PROD, ID_FORN, MAT_FUNC, QTD_PROD, FT_PRODUTO) VALUES ('$nome', '$desc', '$val', '$vld', '$status', '$cat', '$tam', '$cor', '$cbr', '$forn', '$func', '$qtd', '$ft')";
```

Comment: Usei seu método e também o str_replace para substituir o "," por "." na inserção de valores em dinheiro(decimal) no banco de dados, muito obrigado

Comment: Se esta resposta te atendeu, marque como melhor esposta para os outros usuários entenderem isso e não utilizarem o tempo para resolver uma questão que ja foi atendida